# Adding disabled class to checkbox in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

apologies in advance if this question is silly. I am trying to run a check on PHP permissions and if they come back as false, make the checkbox disabled in Knockout (or add a class "disabled" to it). However, not having much luck. My code. Thanks

```
  ax.ko.UserProfileModel = function(data) {
   this.display_name = data.display_name;
   this.enabled = data.enabled;
   this.first_name = data.first_name;
   this.gender = data.gender;
   this.sales_rep_code = data.sales_rep_code;
   this.billable = data.billable;
} 


//VM
ax.ko.UserProfilesVM = function(data) {
var self = this;

 self.userProfile = ko.observableArray([]);
 self.userProfiles = ko.observableArray([]);
 self.isLoading = ko.observable(false);
 self.viewCreateEdit = ko.observable('');
 self.carouselSettings = ax.Carousel.defaults;
 self.canEditAccount = ko.observable();
 self.isBillable = ko.observable();

self.populateUserProfiles = function(data) {
self.userProfiles($.map(data,function(i) { return new 
ax.ko.UserProfileModel(i); }));
};

self.populateUserProfile = function(data) {
 self.userProfile(new ax.ko.UserProfileModel(data));
};
};


<? if ($perms['user_profiles|edit_billable']===FALSE) { ?>
        <div class="field">
        <label><?=l(273)?></label>
        <div class="input">
          <input type="checkbox" name="billable" value="1" data-bind="checked: userProfile().billable, disable:isBillable();">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<? } ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried the "enable" or "disable" binding? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html

Comment: I will try it, I was reading about it but since I'm working through other people's code, was just seeing how I should implement. Thanks man

Comment: thanks @JasonSpake - I tried to no avail. :/

Comment: What exactly did you try and in what way did it not work? We need more information in order to help.

Comment: Thanks I tried adding this  

self.isBillable = ko.observable(); to the model then               
<input type="checkbox" name="billable" value="1" data-bind="disable:isBIllable();">. 
I am probably missing something.

Comment: That should work so there must be something else missing. Can you show more of your code?

Comment: Hi @JasonSpake will update my code

Comment: code updated @JasonSpake included the VM

Comment: You might have a few different problems. userProfile is defined as an array but you're binding to userProfile().billable. Is this inside a nested context? If so which element of the userProfile array are you trying to bind to? Is billable a property on the userProfile model? In your code sample it's unclear.

Comment: hey @JasonSpake I updated the code. Thanks for looking at it. It's a property in the model (we're doing other parts of the code like this - for instance "enabled" mirrors the same exact thing as "billable")

Comment: @erics15, where you able to come alright? another thing to look at is your browser developer console, there could be errors...

Comment: hi @Mosd no errors in the console, still can't get it working

Comment: Why is `userProfile` an `observableArray`?  Please create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 2):

try this, more like you can add disable to your bindings http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/disable-binding.html as suggested by @Jason:

```js
MyVM = function(condition){
    that = this;
    that.flag = ko.observable(true);
    that.condition = ko.observable(condition);
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyVM(true));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>


<div>

<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: flag, disable: condition"/> 

</div>
```